# Why does this OSGi Import-Package not work?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I'm going through this OSGi tutorial (with Eclipse, with the PDE addon installed):

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html

Until task 10 everything worked fine. But now I have a problem:

The "Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0" (which was auto-generated, probably because of the generated Activator class) shows the following error:
"No available bundle exports package 'org.osgi.framework'"

In the Activator class I also get resolve error for classes like BundleActivator and BundleContext. I fixed this problem by using an external jar (org.eclipse.osgi), but I'm pretty sure this isn't the right way to do it, since you're supposed to declare any dependencies in the MANIFEST file.

But how do I add the org.eclipse.osgi jar so the import package line in the manifest is enough?

My entire manifest file:

`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Internal
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.osgi.beispiel.one.bundle.internal
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.osgi.beispiel.one.bundle.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: OSGI
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `org.eclipse.osgi` to the 'Required Plugins' section of the Dependencies tab in the MANIFEST.MF editor (which will add a 'Require-Bundle' line to the MANIFEST.MF).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just got it working by reinstalling it for the third time, and for some reason, this time it automatically chose org.eclipse.core.runtime plugin when creating the project, which also includes the plugin you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for "No available bundle exports package 'org.osgi.framework'" in my workspace was an invalid ${eclipse_home}. The checkbox at "Window - Preferences - Target Platform - Running Platform" was marked with a red icon. I followed "Edit...", select "${eclipse_home}", "Edit...", and checked "This install uses the default configuration area". After leaving the dialogs with "Finish" resp. "OK", the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Eclipse configuration issue; by default, Eclipse has a path defined which is used to locate the bundles - this path may not contain the bundles required by your project, so make sure you add the path where the relevant bundles can be found:

[image]